# How to close node decipher stream on error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to close a decipher stream created with Crypto.createDecipheriv when the readable stream feeding it errors. I am doing this per the recommendation in the docs: "One important caveat is that if the Readable stream emits an error during processing, the Writable destination is not closed automatically. If an error occurs, it will be necessary to manually close each stream in order to prevent memory leaks." https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size. When I call the end() function on the decrypt stream I get an error: `Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`
. How can I close the stream and avoid this error? Here is a full code sample:

```
const Fs = require('fs');
const Crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';
const Iv = Crypto.randomBytes(16);
const key = Crypto.randomBytes(32);

const readStream = Fs.createReadStream('./image1.jpg');
const writeStream = Fs.createWriteStream('./out.file');
const encrypt = Crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, Iv);
writeStream.on('finish', () => {


const readStream2 = Fs.createReadStream('./out.file');
const writeStream2 = Fs.createWriteStream('./out2.jpeg');
const decrypt = Crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, Iv);

    writeStream2.on('finish', () => {

        console.log('fin');
    });
    readStream2.on('error', (err) => {

        console.error(err.message);
        decrypt.end();
        writeStream2.end();
    });
    readStream2.pipe(decrypt).pipe(writeStream2);
    readStream2.emit('error', new Error('Oh Fuck'));
});

readStream.pipe(encrypt).pipe(writeStream);
```